# CMD terminal pass array of args

Tags: shell, cmd, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

Im running the following commands in array it works !

`command: ["k6", "run", "/etc/config/load_test.js"]`

Now when I add just

`--compatibility-mode=base`

I got error , I try it like this

`command: ["k6", "run", "--compatibility-mode", "base", "/etc/config/load_test.js"]`

Any idea what im doing wrong?  https://k6.io/docs/testing-guides/running-large-tests#compatibility-mode=base

**error:** accept one arg(s) receive  2

**if I pass it to to the terminal like this it works**

`k6 run  --compatibility-mode=base someplace/myscript.es5.js`

But not sure how to put it in `array` of args

I've tried also

`command: ["k6", "run", "--compatibility-mode=base", "/etc/config/load_test.js"]` which doesnt work either ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this one:

```
command: ["k6", "run", "--compatibility-mode=base", "/etc/config/load_test.js"]
```

Comment: yes thanks I tried it and it doesnt works , I got error, any other idea?

Comment: Could you show me the error message please so I can have more information to diagnose.

And if this one worked:
```k6 run -o cloud --compatibility-mode=base someplace/myscript.es5.js
```

How about:

```["k6" ,"run", "-o", "cloud", "--compatibility-mode=base", "someplace/myscript.es5.js"]
```